# ElectronJS Multiple Monitors

Tags: electron

I'm attempting to create an application that opens 2 different BrowserWindows in Kiosk mode on 2 attached monitors. The only relevant documentation I see on how to do this is from [this page](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/v0.36.10/docs/api/screen.md) which indicates that the second display should have a bounds > 0. Unfortunately, when I log the *bounds* of each Display, the *x* and *y* properties are 0 on both displays, although the *size.width* and *size.height* appear accurate.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this multi-screen kiosk?

Comment: "the x and y properties are 0 on both displays" very weird! What's your OS?

Answer (score 10):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/screen.md) you could do the following.

```
const electron = require('electron')
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

let win

app.on('ready', () => {
  let displays = electron.screen.getAllDisplays()
  let externalDisplay = displays.find((display) => {
    return display.bounds.x !== 0 || display.bounds.y !== 0
  })

  if (externalDisplay) {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
      x: externalDisplay.bounds.x + 50,
      y: externalDisplay.bounds.y + 50
    })
    win.loadURL('https://github.com')
  }
})
```

Comment: Yes, I've seen that, but as I indicated above, I'm not seeing any display with a bounds.x or bounds.y !== 0. Both displays have bounds == 0.

Comment: Perhaps you can rely on the resolution or any other property that might defer between the screens?